# Not render an option in <p:selectOneRadio>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a p:selectOneRadio

```html
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.value">
    <f:selectItem rendered="#{bean.isbank}" itemLabel="Bank Clients" itemValue="bank" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Contacts" itemValue="contacts" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I want the 'Bank Clients' option not to show every time 'isbank' is false. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

There is an option to disable elements:

```
itemDisabled='#{isbank==false}'
```

Comment: OP asked to hide it, not to disable it.